# When can I replace "through" with "because of". And when should I just stick to "by means of"

Tags: grammar

[image] - All things through His creative power and imagination came into being.

- Through His creative power and imagination, Jesus made all things.

Hello I just learned that ***Through*** can be used to mean because of.

But not everytime. Please take a look at sentences below and let
me know if they're correct:

1. All things because of His creative power and imagination came into
   being. ✅
2. Because of His creative power and imagination, Jesus made all
   things. ❓
3. By means of His creative power and imagination, Jesus made all
   things. ✅

I am fairly certain about #1 and #3, they sound fine.

However #2 sounds sus.

Please let me know if it's correct or not.

Comment: I would render it as _by means of_ rather than _because of_.

Comment: And what about the one that's in passive voice? **All things through his creative power and imagination came into being** . Can I render it as because of or as a result of?

Comment: The sentences say that the 'creative power and imagination' were the _means_ of all things being made, not the _cause_.

Comment: But the footnote read "all things happened because of Him" . And that through [as a result of] His power and imagination, the created order exists.  So I'm confused. If the author sees it as a cause of creation or means of it.

Comment: Is this from a modern translation of the Bible? _You should always give the source of passages you ask questions about._ We're straying into theology here. My comment was based on the way I would normally understand the sentence.

Comment: I'm sorry that wasn't my intention. I was only asking if **Because of His creative power and imagination, Jesus made all things.** was syntactically correct? Because it sounds weird to me.

Answer (score 1):

In most contexts, including yours (although anything theological is likely to be heavily debated), 'through' and 'because of' don't mean the same thing and would not be interchangeable.

- 'Because of' is used to denote the root cause of something happening.
- 'Through' denotes the *means* or *way* that it happened.

I *think* you're referencing John 1:3 which is saying that everything was created 'through' Jesus. Of course, the bible wasn't originally written in English, but if you are using a modern, scholarly translation you should be able to trust the rendering, and you would have to take it that this means God created all things *by means of* Jesus, not 'because' of him.

You will likely know that this verse is just part of a wider statement that includes verse 1, one of the most heavily debated verses in scripture. Some use John 1:1 to support the doctrine of the trinity -  that God and Jesus are the same person because it calls them both 'god'. A scholarly, linguistic view of this is that the original language uses a definite article to distinguish one from the other. This is **not** the site to debate such matters, but I must point this out because your view of this verse will almost certainly influence your understanding of verse 3.

Comment: I know they are not 'always' interchangeable.  +1  .I can't quote the footnote because there's no option to share it through my bible app. It said **through [as a result of] His creative power and imagination** the created order exists.. So I'm just asking if it's syntactically possible to render through as because of in my OP.  **Because of His creative power and imagination, Jesus made all things**

Comment: And the Aramaic doesn't have God made all things through [by the agency of] Jesus unlike the greek version. It has all things happened because of Him. (Jesus)

Comment: @ThatKoko I have added to my answer, maybe that will help. From my personal understanding of this text, and sticking to linguistics because this is not the place for theological debate, I would have to say *no* - it cannot mean that Jesus was the *cause*. All language has to be taken in context, and your understanding of the surrounding verses matters. It may be of interest to you though that the almighty God's personal name includes the verb 'to cause', while Jesus is often called 'the way'. Interesting that these are the same distinctions are the linguistic differences you ask about.

Comment: Ok I found a way to add references. Please take a look at them. Tpt renders john 1:3 as Jesus made all things through His creative power (inspiration). And then the footnote reads, **all things happened because of him**

Comment: So through means as a result of/because of in this context. @Astralbee

Comment: @ThatKoko No! That's exactly what it *doesn't* mean in this context! It means 'by means of'. This isn't the place for theological debate, but you might want to consider it in connection with Proverbs 8:30 which says that Jesus worked alongside God. In light of that, some consider John 1:3 to mean that Jesus was involved in creation but it was God that *caused* it.